# Unity3D rendering issue on android devices

Tags: android, rendering, unity-game-engine

As shown in above screen shots. on some android devices textures are rendering as black. But when I try to capture screen from the device it saved it perfectly alright.

Can anyone please suggest me whats wrong ?

App URL https://play.google.com/store/apps/d...gerz.laststand

Working right on Unity Player, iOS, and some android devices
image 
h**p://forum.unity3d.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=54374&d=1369302221

some android devices not rendering right
h**p://forum.unity3d.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=54373&d=1369302217

findings so far:
Terrain and skybox are rendering without texture (black) rest of the objects are fine properly on Nexus 4 and S3 minis

Comment: How big are the textures which aren't showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed!!

Unity update 4.1.3

Fixes
*Android: Fixed rendering issues on Nexus4 + Android os 4.2.2 when "Use 32bits Display Buffer" is checked, due to Compositor using Default FBO alpha.

Comment: This issue still exist in Unity 4.2. I had to disable 32 bit buffer to solve it.

Comment: I also disabled 32 bit buffer to make terrain texture appear on android device.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the 32 bit buffer in edit/project settings/player build and check if the problem still exists
2. Disable the 24 bit buffer in edit/project settings/player build and check if the problem still exists
3. If you use directional light, go to the direction light inspector and select shadow type `no shadow`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was happening because of sprite that i used from an atlas with the max size set to 4096, i reduced it to 2048 and now every thing works fine, i think its failure in GPU of some weak devices to handling that size.